# addin days in provided date by user

Tags: android, date, days, java.util.calendar, date-manipulation

```
    String pickupdate = pdate.getText().toString().trim();
    // String dateBefore = "25/10/2022";
    // create instance of the SimpleDateFormat that matches the given date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

    //create instance of the Calendar class and set the date to the given date
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    try{
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(pickupdate));
    }catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // use add() method to add the days to the given date
    cal.add(Integer.parseInt(pickupdate), 2); // exception here
    expirydate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
//        Toast.makeText(this, ""+expirydate+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Above is the code where I am getting the pickup date from the user and trying to add 2 days to it using `calender.add` method, but I'm getting error int: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "05-30-2022"`. It happens in the line `cal.add(Integer.parseInt(pickupdate), 2);`. Can somebody body help me this regard?

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this for Android? Which API level? For Java? You seem not to have received much attention yet, and my guess is that adding tags android and/or java would have helped much.

Comment: Define your formatter, say, `dtf` as `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu")`. Parse the input using `LocalDate.parse(pickupdate, dtf)`. Add 2 days through `pickUpLocalDate.plusDays(2)`. Finally format back to string using the same formatter: `expiryLocalDate.format(dtf)`. If this is for Android API level lower than 26, it requires [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).